# Find between which 2 numbers a value lies in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I have a variable @k=35.

and a table xrf having contents as show below.

```
+----+
| tt |
+----+
| 20 |
| 30 |
| 40 |
| 50 |
| 60 |
+----+
```

How to I get the values in between which @k exist in table xrf.

output is 30 and 40.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation

```
select 
  max(case when tt <= @k then tt end) lower, 
  min(case when tt > @k then tt end) upper
from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a clever `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT tt AS upperb, (
    SELECT tt
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE x.tt < t.tt
    ORDER BY tt DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS lowerb
FROM t
WHERE 35 <= tt
ORDER BY tt
LIMIT 1
```